# How to change order status to custom status by product category

Tags: woocommerce

I want it to automatically switch to the special order status when an order is placed from the product category I have determined in the Woocommerce. How should the code be, can you help me?

For example; If a product from the Personalized Products category is in the order, I want it to automatically switch to "wc-prepare" status.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Untested code, but should do the trick

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'custom_order_status_by_cat', 10, 3 );
function custom_order_status_by_cat( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ){
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {      
      $product_id = $item->get_product_id();  
      if ( has_term( 'special-flowers', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) { //enter in your cat i.e special-flowers
         $order->update_status( 'wc-prepare' ); // your status here
         break;
      }
    }
}
```

if you wanna do this for multiple cats

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'custom_order_status_by_cat', 10, 3 );
function custom_order_status_by_cat( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ){
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {      
      $product_id = $item->get_product_id();  
      if ( has_term( 'special-flowers', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) { //enter in your cat i.e special-flowers
         $order->update_status( 'wc-prepare' ); // your status here
         break;
      } else if ( has_term( 'cheap-flowers', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) { //enter in your cat i.e cheap-flowers
         $order->update_status( 'wc-prepare' ); // your status here
         break;
      }
    }
}
```

or if you wanna get fancy you can check if they have items from multiple cats in their cart

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'custom_order_status_by_cat', 10, 3 );
function custom_order_status_by_cat( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ){
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {      
      $product_id = $item->get_product_id();  
      if ( has_term( 'special-flowers', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) { //enter in your cat i.e special-flowers
         if ( has_term( 'cheap-flowers', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) { //enter in your cat i.e cheap-flowers
            $order->update_status( 'wc-prepare' ); // your status here
            break;
         }
      }  
    }
}
```

again, this is untested, but I believe it should work!

Comment: Thank you for support, solved! I have an another question.
When I add the code you send, the order of personalized products automatically switches to wp-prepare. However, orders for personalized products by bank transfer must be on-hold. Now, orders placed by bank transfer automatically switch to wp-prepare. As a result; If the order is a personalized product and a bank transfer, it should be on-hold, and if it is a personalized product and other payment methods, wp-prepare. I would like your help on this subject too.

Comment: Where I should add `if ($order->data['status'] == 'processing') ` on the middle code you provided?