# woocommerce: automatically assign different custom status to an order based on the product ordered

Tags: woocommerce, status

Is there any way of automatically assign different custom status to an order based on the product ordered?

I have a site with subscriptions (monthly/yearly).

**I would like all orders of a specific product (ex: yearly/ID 8386) automatically show the status -> DO NOT SHIP**

And all the rest of the orders/products can be left as normal.

Is this possible?

**In advance thank you for your help and time!**

We use Woocommerce subscription plugin and VIPPS recurring payment. We also use WooCommerce Order Status Manager. But none of the plugins offer automatic change of status that follow parent order to recurring order. If I set the parent order to "do not ship" it does not follow.

I have tried this without it working:

- change order status to custom status by product category
  [How to change order status to custom status by product category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65675499/how-to-change-order-status-to-custom-status-by-product-category/65676142)
- Change order status for virtual, downloadable, free or backorder
  products in WooCommerce [Change order status for virtual, downloadable, free or backorder products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371178/change-order-status-for-virtual-downloadable-free-or-backorder-products-in-woo/61373278#61373278)
- and a couple more....

Comment: Usualy statuses are related to payment method. Do you have single payment method ?

Comment: Hi @MartinMirchev! There are two payment methods on the site. Through telephone/VIPPS and credit card. All products can be bought with both methods.

Comment: Are your products physical or digital/virtual ? Recurring payments should be connected to the order since will repeat same order.

Comment: The products are donations for a charity - so virtual. But the first shipment (parent order) is physical (a gift) and the rest virtual with no shipment involved.

Comment: So if i pay with credit/debit card should be completed on succesfull payment not processing if its virtual. Add checkmark to downloadable too (even if you dont provide anything for download) that will force orders to become completed. What plugin u use for recurring payments ? There should be subscription table in your admin where to check if its recurring payment. Instead of order statuses add new column to your orders named Recurring and next to each order result yes/no for example or color the box green red.

Comment: I use two different plugins - one for credit/debit card (https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions)     and one for telephone/app (https://wordpress.org/plugins/vipps-recurring-payments-gateway-for-woocommerce/ )

Comment: We also use: WooCommerce Order Status Manager. But none of the plugins offer automatic change of status that follow parent order to recurring order. If I set the parent order to "do not ship" it does not follow.

Comment: Like i said making just a new column in your orders will be better over status. From woocommerce subscriptions docs - WC_Subscription::get_related_orders( $return_fields, $order_type ): returns orders relating to a subscription, which can be renewal, switch or parent orders. You can check each order is it parent or renewal and in your column to echo Parent or Renewal. I dont have this plugin to provide you with working solution :/