# change status order for specific category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, onchange, roles, code-snippets

I want to change status order after payment for all products under category private

I tried this code but it works for all products, I need it works with products under category private only

`add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'processing_to_completed');

function processing_to_completed($order_id){

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order->update_status('refunded');
```

}`

can any one help me?

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'processing_to_completed');

function processing_to_completed($order_id){

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order->update_status('refunded');
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65675499/how-to-change-order-status-to-custom-status-by-product-category

Comment: this solution is not working for paid products. it allow them to be confirmed without payment

Comment: This answer is just with different action. From the example you can see how to loop order items and check if item is in specific category. The code that you have provided doesnt check what items you have in the order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the items in your order and if any of the items is from specific category to change the order status.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'processing_to_completed');
    function processing_to_completed($order_id){
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            // check if any of the products is in private category
            if( has_term( array( 'private' ), 'product_cat', $product_id )) {
                $order->update_status( 'refunded' ); // your status here
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'processing_to_completed');
    
    function processing_to_completed($order_id){
      if ( ! $order_id ){
        return;
      }
          
      $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $items = $order->get_items(); 
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {      
          $product_id = $item->get_product_id();  
          if(has_term( 'under-category-private', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) { //enter in your cat i.e           under-category-private 
            $order->update_status( 'under-completed' ); // your own status here
            break;
          }
          else{
            $order->update_status( 'completed' ); // your other status here part from private category not in order.
            break;
          }  
        }
    }
```